# How to handle editing conflicts in Django forms?

Tags: django, concurrency, django-forms, locking

Imagine the following situation: Two users, Alice and Bob, are using a Django form to edit the same object simultaneously. For the purpose of this example, let's use the following model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

Alice edits the book to change its title. Meanwhile, Bob edits the book to change its description. Now, if Bob is the last one to click the "Save" button, his form will "win" and only the description of the book will have been changed. Otherwise, if Alice is the last one to save, only the title will have been changed. Ideally, however, after both forms have been saved, the database should contain the title from Alice, and the description from Bob.

I can think of a few possible solutions to prevent this from happening:

1. Locking the form. As soon as Alice requests the book edit form, she acquires a lock that is released after she clicks "Save". When Bob tries to request the same form, he could get an error or warning message that Alice is already editing the same book. The problem here is if course dealing with stale locks.
2. Checksumming the data being edited. The form could contain a hidden checksum of the underlying data. If the checksum has changed when submitting the form, the user could be warned that the object they are updating was changed in the meantime. It could either prevent them from saving or warn them about it
3. Solving merge conflicts server-side. This is the solution I'd prefer. Somehow, the server should be able to figure out that Alice changed only the title of the book, and Bob changed the description. Perhaps the `ModelForm` could be amended to call `save()` with [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) based on the [`changed_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data) attribute of the form?

I'm sure others have dealt with this problem, and I'm hoping there are existing Django apps out there that implement one of the solutions above. However, I'm having a hard time finding information about this topic. What is the best way to handle editing conflicts in Django forms?

Comment: i think a versioning system like the current SO edit system will be fit for this situation

Answer (score 1):

You can add values in models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
title = models.TextField()
description = models.TextField()
lock = models.BooleanField()
last_change = models.DateTimeField()
last_user_change = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and in view

```
def edit_book(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    user = request.user.id 
    if book.lock == 0:
        book.lock = 1
        book.save()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = edit_bookForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                f=form(commit=False)
                f.last_change = datetime.now()
                f.last_user_change = user
                f.save()
                book.lock = 0
                book.save()
             return redirect('ok')
         return render(request, 'urformhtml.html', {})
     else:
         return render(request, 'byebye.html', {})
```

Or you can add last_change_title and last_change_description to split update....

Is only an idea

Comment: Great idea! This completely answers point 1 of the question!

Comment: Maybe `book.update(lock=True)`  would avoid having to call the `save()` method?